# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean HasFlag(System.Enum)' when creating the expression via System.Linq.Expressions.Expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, enums

We are using `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression` to build custom expressions which are applied on the `.Where()` of our `IQueryable`.

What I want to achieve is, to apply the `.HasFlag()` method ([introduced in EF 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10322388/using-a-enum-with-flag-in-an-entity-framework-query)) on the property which is then used in the `.Where()` expression.

I have following code:

```
var memberExpression = propertyExpression as MemberExpression;
var targetType = memberExpression?.Type ?? typeof(decimal?);
var value = Enum.Parse(type, searchValue);
var hasFlagMethod = targetType.GetMethod(nameof(Enum.HasFlag));
var hasFlagExpression = Expression.Call(propertyExpression, hasFlagMethod, Expression.Convert(Expression.Constant(value), typeof(Enum)));
```

The value of `propertyExpression` is being displayed as `{x.Type}` and the `hasFlagMethod` is being shown as `{Boolean HasFlag(System.Enum)}` which both look fine to me.

The value of `hasFlagExpression` is `{x.Type.HasFlag(Convert(Foo))}` which also looks completely fine to me except the `Convert(Foo)` part but doing this was necessary otherwhise I would get another Exception that it is complaining that the parameter cannot be applied to this method as it is not `System.Enum`.

And at the time we enumerate the `IQueryable` with this `.Where()` we get following exception:

```
NotSupportedException: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
'Boolean HasFlag(System.Enum)' method, and this method cannot
be translated into a store expression.
```

Calling it directly on the `IQueryable` works though (we are also using EF 6.1 which added support for `Enum.HasFlag()`) as in

```
Entities.Where(x => x.Type.HasFlag(BarEnum.Foo));
```

But calling it like this is not an option as it needs to be generic for all our entities. (We put those `.Where()` conditions together according to the filtered columns in our Datatables)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a small not easily visible difference between the [`MethodInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) of the `HasFlag` method in your code and the one generated by the compiler. The [`ReflectedType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.reflectedtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property in the former case is `typeof(YourEnum)` while in the later - `typeof(Enum)`. The [`DeclaringType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx) property in both cases is one and the same - `typeof(Enum)`, hence the debug display, but that's enough to break the EF query translator.

To fix the issue, simply change

```
var hasFlagMethod = targetType.GetMethod(nameof(Enum.HasFlag));
```

to

```
var hasFlagMethod = typeof(Enum).GetMethod(nameof(Enum.HasFlag));
```

Comment: Oh wow, this didn't come to my mind, I thought that it should work as my property is also an enum. Thanks for your answer, I'll immediately try tomorrow at work and reply if it worked out! :-)